# How to count Elements on Webpage with Java & Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

my webpage contains several Elements with an xpath locator like:

```
//li[2]/div/div[2]/div
//li[3]/div/div[2]/div
//li[4]/div/div[2]/div
...
...
```

I need to know how many of those elements are displayed. How can i count them using `Java` and `Selenium`?

Thnx

Roland

Comment: You'll have to make your XPath a little more agnostic, so it isn't so tightly bound to it's surroundings (your XPath at the moment is very position-based, which isn't great). Perhaps show us a copy of the HTML, that shows these multiple elements, so we can see the unique qualities of the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try driver.find_elements_by_xpath and count the number of returned elements.

```
int xpathCount = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("Valid_Xpath")).size();
```

For more info [click here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/12b82ra54t/xpath-for-counting-number-of-rows-in-a-table-webdriver) or [here.](http://seleniumtesting-nx.blogspot.in/2012/03/xpath-count-in-selenium2-webdriver.html)

Valid_Xpath should be xpath of First form element in the HTML.

Comment: Hi Chetan, can you explain "xpath of First form element in the HTML" using int xpathCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[2]/div/div[2]/div")).size(); returns 1 as i expect, but that's not the number i'm looking for

Comment: Just read 4.3 point of the doc.https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

Comment: In doc, see the HTML contains login form. i want no. of xpths in form then i use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[1]"). same in your application use the first form element.

Comment: Hi,

using int xpathCount2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/ul/*")).size(); insteadt of int xpathCount1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[2]/div/div[2]/div")).size(); returns the expected ammount of elements! Thank you very much Chetan

Roland