# Selenium How do I find .size of same id with different attributes

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am looking for this unique ID "tleid" which has an incrementing attribute ranging from 0-9. I want to find how many "tleid" have loaded on the page.

This is what loads : `<li class:blah tleid="number range from 0-9">`
I am trying to look it up by using xpath 
`"//li[contains(@tleid, '[0-9]')]"` 
but can't get it to work.

Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findElements` to find all elements, an use `size()` to count them.

You xpath selector should be:

```
//li[@tleid]
```

You can also use css selector:

```
li[tleid]
```

For count here is a similar post [count elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559237/how-to-count-elements-on-webpage-with-java-selenium).

Comment: Thanks, knew there was something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following XPATH to retrieve a list web elements contains **tleid attribute** and then count the list items:

```
//*[@tleid]
```